# Unable to start 2nd view function

Tags: python, django

Currently, im trying to make it so that I can complete a question on a page then when it's submitted to the database the next page will load. furthermore, every time I point it towards the templates folder it is piggybacking off the original one meaning that it can't find the new HTML page.

My idea is that when question1 is completed it will link to question2 where the def question2 code will execute and so on. But the forms won't display correctly and I believe it is due to the def question2 not running correctly.

```
def question1(request):
    question_form1 = QuestionForm1()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # saves to database
            return HttpResponse('question2.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'music/failed.html')
    return render(request, 'music/question1.html', locals())


def question2(request):
    question_form2 = QuestionForm2()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = QuestionForm2(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
                form2.save()  # Saves to database
                return render(request, 'music/question3.html', locals())
        else:
                return render(request, 'music/failed.html')
    return render(request, 'music/question2.html', locals())
```

Edit:**Added Urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    app_name = 'music'

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
        url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
        url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
        url(r'^question1/$', views.question1, name='question1'),
        url(r'^question2/$', views.question2, name='question2'),

    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# delete following line
return HttpResponse('question2.html')`

# replace with this one
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_name_here'))

# or if you are using any namespaces for your url
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('namespace:view_name_here'))
```

Comment: this is throwing up an error.  Reverse for 'music.views.question2' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: May I see your `urls.py` file, please?

Comment: Completed. @nik_m Is there a way of communicating with you, as for your help i want to inform you of what I'm creating.

Comment: Sure. My twitter account is [this](https://twitter.com/ManikosN). Follow me and we can talk there!

Comment: Ok, I'v followed you

Comment: Urls.py has been added.

Comment: Please open a console and write `from django.urls import reverse` and then `reverse('question2')` or `reverse('register')`, What do you get?

Comment: Im not able to run these commands as im using Windows Powershell for my console. Its not able to run these commands

Comment: Why not? Can't you just go to the project's directory and do a `python manage.py shell` and then the ones above!

Comment: Have you used any namespace for your app (music) inside your root `urls`? The `urls.py` file that is under your root project, not the one that is under your app. If so, then you must write it like this: `reverse('namespace:question2')`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this but its not working, I've resorted to using return render again, and I've now got it to post to the 2nd page but the form for question2.html is not displaying even though i have confirmed its all correct and links.